# No C++ IDE Is Working Anymore?

Tags: windows, ide, mingw, linker-errors, dev-c++

About a week ago I installed a MinGW installer to see if I can get the compiler itself without the IDE and nothing happened, but now every time I open a C++ IDE, it always gives me errors when I compile even when it has the main method generated and I try to run it, it just gives me errors. In devc++ this is what is get with this code:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
cin.get();
}
```

Here are the errors:

> In function '_mingw_CRTStartup':
>   [Linker error] undefined reference to '_dyn_tls_init_callback'
>   [Linker error] undefined reference to '_cpu_features_init'
>   id returned 1 exit status

Every IDE tells me different errors, but they worked before I got the thing installed and I tried to uninstall it, but nothing happened. What kinda thing is doing this?

Comment: Probably would've just been a warning, but `main` needs to return an int.  You're returning nothing.

Comment: @prelic in C++ the `return` statement in optional.

Comment: I would try and get it working via the command-line first.  This will bisect your problem.

Comment: This is actually a recurring problem for users who have multiple versions of MinGW installed. This is the case for you? And Dev-C++ (especially if it's the Bloodshed version) is better avoided.

Answer (score 0):

I had this same exact problem and it took me a week to figure out the solution. First delete/uninstall eclipse, MinGW, and any other IDE'S then Try this...
**Defragment your computer:**
  -step 1: click start menu.
  -step 2: search for "defragmenter" and click on it.
  -step 3: click on "Defragment disk" icon (not the "analyze disc" icon).
**clean your C drive**
  -step 1: click start menu.
  -step 2: search for "disk cleanup".
  -step 3: check all box icons under "files to delete".
  -step 4: click on ok.
Now reinstall your IDE's(eclipse, mingw, etc) and put back all your stuff and it should work like a charm! Hope this helps!